# Share WLAN networks I select

Tags: 8.1, 8.1-update-1, networking

In my `WLAN Sense` application there is a choice named `Share WLAN networks I select`. What does it exactly mean? I Googled the phrase and could not find anyone who mentions it.

Answer (score 1):

It allows your connections on social networks to use the same wireless key to connect to the WiFi networks you have keys for